# Postgres match data in string array

Tags: postgresql

I have a postgres table where the column type is text but it has data which looks like in an array:

```
["97aa63c0-c562-11e3-b216-000180810a27","33fff220-b6be-11e3-be89-000180810a27"]
```

My first question is what is this data structure?

How can I match in a query: For Example:

If the table name id X and column name where data exist is products

```
Select * from X where product='97aa63c0-c562-11e3-b216-000180810a27'
```

How can I do something like that?

Comment: You mean column `product` has comma separated values like `97aa63c0-c562-11e3-b216-000180810a27,33fff220-b6be-11e3-be89-000180810a27`? that's a bad DB design. Try normalizing your table and don't store comma separated values.

Comment: it also has brackets just like I put it. all ids are inside those brackets.

Comment: That's too great then. in that case `=` will not help. try using `LIKE` instead saying `where product='%97aa63c0-c562-11e3-b216-000180810a27%'`

Comment: Can we use ANY in that case. https://coderwall.com/p/jmtskw

Comment: don't think so cause in your case it's `TEXT` type column and not array type but not sure though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That looks like a json or python array literal containing uuid values.

There are [many reasons not to store data like this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/55871/postgresql-list-of-integers-separated-by-comma-or-integer-array-for-performance) but it sounds like you didn't design the DB.

In modern PostgreSQL I'd parse it as json. In older versions I'd use string functions to convert it. In 9.4 this will work:

```
WITH arr(uuids) AS (
  VALUES('["97aa63c0-c562-11e3-b216-000180810a27","33fff220-b6be-11e3-be89-000180810a27"]')
)
SELECT 
  elem::uuid
FROM arr, json_array_elements_text(
  uuids::json
) elem;
```

but 9.3 doesn't have `json_array_elements_text` so you have to write:

```
WITH arr(uuids) AS (VALUES('["97aa63c0-c562-11e3-b216-000180810a27","33fff220-b6be-11e3-be89-000180810a27"]'))
SELECT json_array_element(uuids::json, ss-1) FROM arr, generate_series( 1, json_array_length(uuids::json) ) ss;
```

and in still older versions:

```
WITH arr(uuids) AS (VALUES('["97aa63c0-c562-11e3-b216-000180810a27","33fff220-b6be-11e3-be89-000180810a27"]'))
    SELECT left(right(elem,-1),-1)::uuid FROM arr, unnest(string_to_array(left(right(uuids, -1),-1), ',')) elem;
```

Comment: I am unable to see some part of the answer looks like scroller is not showing up.